# Simple recursive iteration over a singly linked list JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list

I'm working on getting started with JavaScript. I implemented a simple function to convert an array to a singly linked list, and then iterate over it recursively to return the value at a particular position. My code currently logs `undefined` for all position values except 0. What causes it to behave this way?

```
var list = arrayToList([1,2,3,4,5]);

function arrayToList(arr) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value : arr[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}

function nth(list, count) {
  if (!list) return undefined;
  if (count == 0) return list.value;
  else nth(list.rest, count - 1);
}

console.log(nth(list,2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "else" clause in the `nth` function does not return a value, so `undefined` is returned by default.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example over here

https://github.com/aloksguha/smartll

or you can try it out as node library. "smart-ll".